# ASP.NET exec after publish happens

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, publish

I'm stuck and I can't find really anything in searching. I have a standard ASP.Net web project (framework 4.8) in Visual Studio 2019. This is not a core.net app. What I want to do is to execute a command after I publish the app to a folder. In the .csproj file I am able to perform an action just before the files are copied by adding this in --

```
<Target Name="CustomPostPublishAction" AfterTargets="CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackage">
 <Exec Command="..\MyProject.Build\Build.bat" />
</Target>
```

But I would like to execute a command after it publishes my files out to the folder. I've tried this

```
<Target Name="CustomAction" AfterTargets="Publish">
   <Exec Command="..\MyProject.Build\AfterPublish.bat" />
</Target>
```

and

```
<Target Name="CustomAction" AfterTargets="AfterPublish">
   <Exec Command="..\MyProject.Build\AfterPublish.bat" />
</Target>
```

Neither of these work. Any ideas?

Comment: "Neither of these work" - **be more specific** - is it just not running your `.bat` file at all? How can you tell it's not running? Have you tried using `$()` variables instead of hardcoding a relative path?

Comment: Does it currently report any errors?

Comment: The bat file will not run. If I put everything under CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackage I can see it's running. No errors are reported. This seems to be a very under documented feature with Visual Studio. Even the MSDN docs give it very few paragraphs and mostly it has to do with MSBuild not deploying. If could figure out how to deploy the files myself I would just skip using the Publish tool in Visual Studio.